# Как, при наведении мышки, менять стиль у нескольких элементов, кроме текущего?

Tags: javascript

Есть группа элементов. Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении мышки на один `div` менялось значение у остальных?

Хочу добиться этого на чистом JavaScript без jQuery. Покажите, пожалуйста, пример функции.

Comment: зависит от того, какими элементами ты хочешь управлять - родителем, соседними, дочерними... а самое событие наведения `mouseover`, например - почитать вот тут можешь: (https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave) - там и примеры есть

Comment: вот простой пример, основную идею поймешь, думаю http://codepen.io/lexxl/pen/gPMWpj

Comment: Мне нужно просто менять css свойство у нескольких элементов, но так что вот у меня пять элементов и при наведении на один(любой) менялся цвет других четырех, просто в js я не очень не могли бы продемонстрировать пример функции пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

document.getElementById('bl').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(blocks, function(el) {
    el.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sel {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="block sel" id="bl">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
```

---

**Обновление после комментария**

Для того, чтобы ловить события всех блоков, можно сделать так:

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  var bg = 'red';
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('block')) {
    bg = '';
  }
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(blocks, function(el) {
    if (el !== e.target) 
      el.style.background = bg;
    else
      el.style.background = '';
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" id="bl">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно просто менять css свойство у нескольких элементов, но так что вот у меня пять элементов и при наведении на один(любой) менялся цвет других четырех, просто в js я не очень не могли бы продемонстрировать пример функции пожалуйста?

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: в FireFox во втором примере красными становятся все.

Comment: Само собой, как и в хроме. Насколько я понимаю - это ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: «пять элементов и при наведении на один(любой) менялся цвет других четырех» – как я понял, нужно другое поведение.

Comment: Оу, не заметил - исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так - при событии сравнивать все элементы внутри контейнера с `target`'ом события. Таргету (над кем мышка) снимать класс, всем остальным ставить:

```js
var root = document.getElementById('container')
    ,elements = root.children
    ,onOver = function(e){
      for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        if( elements[i] === e.target) {
          elements[i].setAttribute("class", "");
        } else {
          elements[i].setAttribute("class", "active");
        }
      }
    }
    ,onOut = function(e){
      for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        elements[i].setAttribute("class", "");
      }
    }
;
    
root.addEventListener('mouseover', onOver);
root.addEventListener('mouseout', onOut);
```

```css
body {font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt}
#container div{cursor:pointer;width:70px;padding:2px;margin-right:4px;border:1px solid #999;float:left}
.active {background-color:#CCC}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Пункт 1</div>
  <div>Пункт 2</div>
  <div>Пункт 3</div>
  <div>Пункт 4</div>
  <div>Пункт 5</div>
</div>
```